# Select rows based on customer ids in R o

Tags: mysql, r

I have a big log record data in csv, including customer id, Date, Action and other columns.

Now I need filter out the record rows with these customer ids (which I need to look at, about 2000 customer ids).

How can I find these rows? And how can Ifind the last 3 Action they did for each of these ids?

Comment: It will be easier to answer if you provide [a reproducible example](http://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/reprex.html).  At a minimum a sample of the data (preferably using R's `dput` command so we can reproduce the data structure), and ideally the code you have tried so far.  And can you clarify whether you want all the customer ids, or do you have a list of ids you want to look for?

Comment: I might recommend handling this on the MySQL side and configuring your logger to behave the way you seem to need.  And yes you should show us some data.

Comment: the data not in database, therefore i cannot use mysql to handle. :(

Comment: @Eric And can you clarify whether you want all the customer ids, or do you have a list of ids you want to look for?----》 i just want filter according to the list of id i need, not all the customer ids.

Answer (score 0):

To answer yout first question, first filter the ids:

```
df %>% filter(ids %in% list)
```

in `list` you need a list with the 2000 ids you are looking for. `df` is the dataframe you imorted into R. Also check the exact Columname of `ids`, (`Ids`, `id's`...)